# Change value in external Iframe

Tags: iframe

I wonder if there is a way to make a universal seltor ...
I have adsense ... but this has several iframes in your ad ... one inside the other ...
tried using jquery to modify oo-value "" the object, but does not work ... because the script is external ...

is there any way to change the value with JS ...

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://static.ny.us.criteo.net/flash/g2/n/n_v3.7_336x280.swf" width="336" height="280" id="cto336x280_divda84232ee6">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="flashvars" value="rerr>
</object>
```

Comment: Unlikely possible. Google for *cross-domain scripting*